# template type miss match

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library

I have this code :

```
template <typename T>
struct ObjectPCD
{

    bool bcl;
    typename pcl::PointCloud<T>::Ptr pcd_object;

};

class SegmentingTool
{
public:
template <typename T>
    std::vector<ObjectPCD> classifyParts(typename std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<T> >* resultVec)
    {
     std::vector<ObjectPCD> rArt;
     return rArt;
     }
};
```

I do not understand why am I getting this compilation error:

```
error: type/value mismatch at argument 1 in template parameter list for ‘template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> class std::vector’
  std::vector<ObjectPCD> classifyParts(typename std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<T> >* resultVec)
```

Comment: Remove ``typename`` in this line ``std::vector<ObjectPCD> classifyParts(typename std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<T> >* resultVec)``

Comment: @BrainStone, I tried. Same error. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you write:

```
std::vector<ObjectPCD>
```

`std::vector` expects a *type* for the first template parameter. But `ObjectPCD` isn't a type - it's a class template:

```
template <typename T>
struct ObjectPCD { ... };
```

Perhaps you meant:

```
std::vector<ObjectPCD<T>>
```

?

Answer (score 1):

You have some severe errors with your generic code. First of all `typnename` shouldn't be in the parameter list. Then you also forgot to add `<T>` to `ObjectPCD` (This is causing the error by the way).

Here is your code fixed:

```
template <typename T>
    std::vector<ObjectPCD<T> > classifyParts(std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<T> >* resultVec)
    {
     std::vector<ObjectPCD<T> > rArt;
     return rArt;
     }
```

Comment: gcc compiler complains about std::vector<ObjectPCD<T>>, i changed it to std::vector<ObjectPCD<T> > and it works!

Comment: @Samer I typically use a different compiler which I don't have this issue with. But I will update my answer to address this issue. Also please remember to upvote and accept my answer if it solved your problem!

Comment: @Brian Don't be a dick. Also, the extra `typename` isn't a bug. It's just... extra.

Comment: @BrainStone you have a point, I will consider this next time.